# In Ansible, how to get a variable from another variable and then fetch its value

Tags: ansible

Here is my problem I need to use one variable '`RDS_SG_NAME`' and then append '_id' to it's value to get another variable name which value I want/need. My simple playbook look like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no 
  vars:
    abc_id: 'some-value'
    RDS_SG_NAME: 'abc'
    RDS_SG_ID: "{{ RDS_SG_NAME +'_id' }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ RDS_SG_NAME }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ RDS_SG_ID }}"
```

when I run this playbook, it give the values like this:

RDS_SG_NAME: abc
  RDS_SG_ID: abc_id

But I want the some-value againt it, can someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. So to be clear, what should `RDS_SG_ID` evaluate to?

Comment: OK I think you want `RDS_SG_ID` to _point_ to the variable called `abc_id` instead of holding the string `abc_id`

Comment: There is no eval in Ansible/Jinja AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

In case your variable declaration only is defined like this for simplification of the example, there might be a chance. All group and host vars are accessible from the dict `hostvars`.

So if your vars actually are defined as host or group vars, you could do something like this:

```
hostvars[ansible_hostname][RDS_SG_ID]
```

If you really define the vars in the playbook, there still might be a chance. By showing the contents of `hostvars` (without a hostname) I can see your local variables in the dict:

```
TASK: [debug msg="{{ hostvars }}"] ******************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "\"{'inventory_hostname': '127.0.0.1', 'inventory_hostname_short': '127', 'abc_id': 'some-value', 'ansible_python_interpreter': '/usr/bin/python', 'RDS_SG_ID': \"{{RDS_SG_NAME"
```

`RDS_SG_ID` is unevaluated and suddenly stops, which might be an error in the debug module. But `abc_id` certainly is there. The funny thing though is, I was not able to extract it from the dict. Whatever value you directly try to access, the error message will be

> host not found: abc_id

Which makes sense. But calling it with a hostname results in a dict which does not contain the defined vars. So the value is in a dict but you can't access it. If you define vars locally in the playbook and need to access them, this might be something to investigate though.

Other than that, Jinja/Ansible does not have an `eval` function.